# EF Core 2.0 - filtering IQueryable navigation property collection empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Tech:

- EF Core 2.0.0
- Asp.Net Core Mvc 2.0.0

When i execute this method it throws *"InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element"* on evaluating CurrentGrade. Why does it throw and how can I fix it?

I have a search method filtering on quite a lot of properties on a large dataset (10 000 users with thousands of related entities). I'm trying to optimize the query and i don't want to execute the query until all filtering has been made. While using ToList() makes the method work i would rather work against an IQueryable and execute the query when done filtering.

I'm pretty sure this worked before updating EF Core from 1.x to 2.0.

```
  public MemberQueryResult Search(MemberQuery filter)
        {
            var query = Context.Users
                .Include(x => x.Honours)
                .Include(x => x.Grades)
                .Include(x => x.Strokes)
                .Include(x => x.Posts)
                .Include(x => x.Loge)
                .AsNoTracking();

            query = query.ApplyFiltering(filter);

            return result;
        }
```

ApplyFiltering() works well for filtering on foreign keys but when filtering on a navigation property collection using .Where() it throws on ICollection Grades on Member when just before the filtering it was included.

This is the method inside ApplyFiltering() that throws:

```
  private static IQueryable<Member> SearchByCurrentGradeRange(MemberQuery filter, IQueryable<Member> result)
    {
        if (filter.GradeRange == null) return result;

        var gradeRange = filter.GradeRange.Split(',');
        var gradeFrom = (Grade)int.Parse(gradeRange[0]);
        var gradeTo = (Grade)int.Parse(gradeRange[1]);

        result = result.Where(x => x.CurrentGrade >= gradeFrom && x.CurrentGrade <= gradeTo);

        return result;
    }
```

CurrentGrade is a calculated property on a member, Grade is just an enum.:

```
    public sealed class Member : IdentityUser
{
        public Grade CurrentGrade => Grades.OrderBy(x => x.Grade).Last(x => x.ReceivedDate != null).Grade;

        public ICollection<MemberGrade> Grades { get; set; } = new Collection<MemberGrade>();

}
```

Comment: Try adding an Include(x => x.CurrentGrade) to your Search query object.

Comment: @LazyCoder I get an exception:

`An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The property 'CurrentGrade' is not a navigation property of entity type 'Member'. The 'Include(string)' method can only be used with a '.' separated list of navigation property names.`

Comment: Yea, I see it now, so that's not it.  But I think because you're doing .AsNoTracking() and then trying to .Where() it later in life, it is not liking that...maybe try dropping that, don't .ToList() just leave it as it is.

Comment: @Lindeberg I don't this was working before migrating to EF Core 2.0. Are you sure you have CurrentGrade as a filter and no exception occured?

Comment: @LazyCoder

Not using AsNoTracking() and only using AsQueryable() makes no difference.

Comment: @CodeNotFound I cannot promise this worked before EF Core 2.0 update but I want to believe so yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the unmapped ("calculated") property is causing [client evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval), but at the time EF evaluates the client part of the `Where` clause, the navigation properties are not loaded yet, hence your `Grades` collection is empty (as it has been iinitialized with `new Collection<MemberGrade>` - if you remove the initializer, then you'll get `NullReferenceException`).

Now, probably it could be treated as EF Core bug. But I strongly recommend **not using** unmapped properties in LINQ queries in general, and especially in query filter conditions. Even if they work, the client evaluation will cause loading a lot of data in memory just to apply the filter there, rather than at the database (SQL) side.

Also make sure to use SQL translatable constructs. For instance, `Last` / `LastOrDefault` have no natural SQL translation, while `FirstOrDefault` does, so the usual pattern is `OrderByDescending().FirstOrDefault()` rather than `OrderBy().LastOrDefault()`.

With that being said, the working server side evaluating solution in your case would be like this:

```
result = result.Where(m => m.Grades
    .Where(x => x.ReceivedDate != null).OrderByDescending(x => x.Grade).Take(1)
    .Any(x => x.Grade >= gradeFrom && x.Grade <= gradeTo));
```

Comment: Thanks for the great, correct answer. Could you also provide some ideas on keeping it object oriented with a way to use calculated properties like this in LINQ to SQL? 

@Ivan Stoev I feel there must be a common best practice for this, but I have trouble finding it on google.. There's some talk about expressions but that still doesn't feel optimal because the logic should be ON the object with property or method, right?

Comment: Right. But OOP, especially encapsulation doesn't play well with LINQ query translation which is based on the opposite principle - knowledge, i.e. to being able to traverse the expression tree and map the recognized methods/constructs. There are no objects at that time at all. Shortly, in EFC you have to choose between  (1) object oriented, but inefficient and (2) non object oriented, but efficient.

Comment: Thanks. Holy shit, why isn't this being talked about more I wonder, while working with a large database.. In EFC you say - do you mean it's different in EF6? At least there is support for the package I found "DelegateDecompiler" which kinda solves it.

Comment: In EF6 you cannot even include non recognizable method in the query. It compiles successfully (as any valid C# code), but at runtime you get the famous `NotSupportedException` *LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'SomeMethodName' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.* DelegateDecompliler is an interesting project, I've never tried it, but it looks promising (as soon as it works).